# Autodoc class with multiple signatures

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, python-typing

I have the following http client class

```py
class MyClient:
  """Class docstring"""

  @overload
  def __init__(self, url): ...

  @overload
  def __init__(self, *, scheme, auth, host, port, path): ...

  def __init__(self, url=None, **kwargs): ...
```

and I'd like to generate the Sphinx documentation for the class's two signatures.

I can use `py:class` and write the two signatures by hand, but this solution requires me to copy the docstring violating DRY.

```
.. py:class:: MyClient(url)
              MyClient(*, scheme, auth, host, port, path)

    Class docstring
```

On the other hand, using `autoclass` will fetch the docstring automatically, but does not allow specifying multiple singatures.

```
.. autoclass:: MyClient
```

generates

*class* **MyClient**(url=None, **kwargs)
    Class docstring

Is there a way to write two signatures and insert class' docstring automatically at the same time?

Comment: Since noone seems to have a clue, an alternative would be to write `@classmethod`s instead of overloading `__init__`. e.g., keep the middle one and have a `from_url(cls, url=None, **kwargs)`.

Comment: See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3610